# ColdFusion handling of datatables "sent parameters"

Tags: arrays, struct, datatables, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Anyone have experience with using jQuery datatables with ColdFusion? Did you have any success in using the "serverSide" mode, in getting CF to properly parse the parameters sent by datatables to the server into complex variables? For example, currently if I dump the "form" I'm getting keys like `columns[1][data]` or `search[value]`. How do I get ColdFusion to parse these parameters into variables like `form.columns[1].data` or `form.search.value`?

According to the documentation at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side, it says:

> In most modern server-side scripting environments this data will automatically be available to you as an array.

I'm using ColdFusion 11.

Comment: Please include your code and the dump in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out a utility called FormUtils.

It can take this

```
<h2 class="is-size-2">employee[1]</h2>
<input name="employee[1].name" type="text" value=""><br />
<input name="employee[1].phone" type="text" value=""><br />
<input name="employee[1].permission.2" type="text" value=""><br />
<input name="employee[1].permission.1" type="text" value=""><br />
<input name="employee[1].mode[2]" type="text" value=""><br />
<input name="employee[1].mode[1]" type="text" value=""><br />
```

And turn it into structs and arrays

```
 <cfset util = new formutils.FormUtils().init() />
 <!--- form has been patched --->
 <cfdump var="#form#">
```

It basically allows forms to be pushed over as structs and arrays

**Disclaimer**

I rewrote the original. The original was done by Brian Kotek.

The links below are to my version of the code. There are also links to his version.

Video demo of it in action: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/10/make-form-processing-simpler-with-brian-koteks-formutils/

Core file: https://github.com/jmohler1970/FormUtils

Demo site: https://github.com/jmohler1970/FormUtils_demo

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go.